# Override Spring Security configure(HttpSecurity) when overridden in a Maven dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Maven Spring Boot 2 with Spring Security project. One of the maven dependencies extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. e.g.,

```
public class MyConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"))
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll()
                .successHandler(myLoginHandler)
                .failureHandler(formAuthFailureHandler)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(logoutUrl()))
                .logoutSuccessUrl(logoutSuccessUrl())
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(publicRoutes())
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT).authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH).authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE).denyAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
}
```

The problem is in this application I need to override `successHandler()` and add a logout handler like this `logout().addLogoutHandler(myLogoutHandler)`.

Is it possible to just update these bits, or will I need to define the whole chain again? Maybe something like this,

```
public class AnotherConfig extends MyConfig {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"))
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll()
                .successHandler(myLoginHandler)
                .failureHandler(formAuthFailureHandler)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .addLogoutHandler(myLogoutHandler)
                .permitAll()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(logoutUrl()))
                .logoutSuccessUrl(logoutSuccessUrl())
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(publicRoutes())
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT).authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH).authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE).denyAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
}
```

I was hoping there might be a single setter for these two values somewhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set order of overriding one to higher that overridden one.

```
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 1)
public class AnotherConfig extends MyConfig {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"))
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll()
                .successHandler(myLoginHandler)
                .failureHandler(formAuthFailureHandler)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .addLogoutHandler(myLogoutHandler)
                .permitAll()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(logoutUrl()))
                .logoutSuccessUrl(logoutSuccessUrl())
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(publicRoutes())
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT).authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH).authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE).denyAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
}
```

Why `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 1`?
Because the default order is `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE` as set for overridden class.

Or you can set it a specific number for overridden.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if ordering will help, but I'll take another look. The maven dependency where this is defined has `@Order(10)`. What I want to do is just set the two handlers without defining the whole chain again. It's actually working the way I described in my question, I just want to override the login/logout handlers if possible.